# Play Audio-Stream from Java-Application in HTML5-Audio-Tag

Tags: audio-streaming, html5-audio, server-push, webkitaudiocontext

I've spent now almost a week trying to play an audio-stream in the browser sent from my java application. Playing a single file is not the problem. What I want to achieve is playing a constant stream (sent in form of byte-array-chunks) from a java application by pushing the arrays via ServerPush/Comet/Atmosphere to the client.
I have tried using Chrome 27.0.1453.94 m, Firefox 21.0 and IE 10.

I have been working with the [Web Audio API W3C drafts definition](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html), also some articles on html5rocks ([an intro](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/), [Web Audio API and Audio-Tag](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/HTML5-audio-and-the-Web-Audio-API-are-BFFs)) and also [this](http://9elements.com/html5demos/audio/).
For receiving binary data I have found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data).
Moreover as of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp) ogg should be playable in Chrome and Firefox.

Using Flash is not really an option as then I would need a complete different setup on the server (with RTP-Streams, etc.) and there also would be bad support for mobile devices.

I would appreciate any hints on what I'm doing wrong or a way that works to play audio.
Below I posted my setup.

**My Setup:**

I have a "Stream-Service"-Class which reads audio files, transcodes them to ogg (if necessary) with [JAVE](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/) and then submits byte-arrays to the client.
I use Atmosphere to push new audio chunks to the client (The HTTP-ResponseType is set to "arraybuffer").
Each byte-array that is pushed to the client is of 1400 bytes size and is base64- and json-encoded serverside.

In Javascript I have approx. the following code (some parts left out as not relevant for the problem):

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

var initStreaming = {
  audioContext : {},
  source : {},
  socket : $.atmosphere,
  transport : 'websocket',

  connect : function() {
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.controls = true;
    audio.autoplay = true;
    audio.volume = 0.5;
    audio.oncanplay = function() {
      console.log("Has audio to play.");
      // Just for test purposes: This message is never printed...
    };
    document.body.appendChild(audio);

    this.audioContext = new AudioContext();
    // Firefox doesn't seem to know this function:
    this.source = this.audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    // For this I also have tried using this in Firefox - but then FF crashes without warning:
    // this.source = this.audioContext.createBufferSource();
    this.source.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
    this.socket.subscribe(this.request);
  },
  request : {
    // ... request config and some onXY-Methods left out here
    onMessage : function(response) {
      try {
        var json = $.parseJSON(response.responseBody);
        // The next 4 Statements is to get an ArrayBuffer out of the JSON Object to pass to 'decodeAudioData'
        var blob = new Blob(json, {type : 'arraybuffer'});
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function() {
          initStreaming.audioContext.decodeAudioData(
            this.result, // Argument must be of type ArrayBuffer
            function(decodedBuffer) {
              initStreaming.source.buffer = decodedBuffer;
              initStreaming.source.start(0);
            },
            function(error) {
              // Chrome always goes straight to this part.
              console.log("An error in decodeAudioData");
              // In Chrome error is null
              console.debug(error);
            });
          };
          fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("OOOOPPPS!");
          console.log(error);
        }
     }
  }
};

window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  initStreaming.connect();
});
```

Comment: Not related, but why are you creating a `new Audio()` when you don't use it at all?

Comment: I'm quite new to this HTML5/audio-stuff - so my guess is I'm doing something wrong. But it's used here? => this.source = this.audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio);